# NLog - modifying exception message

Tags: c#, .net, exception, logging, nlog

Is there a way to modify the message written by NLog when logging exceptions? E.g.: by registering a function that receives the message as a parameter and returns the message to be logged as output. The goal is to identify sensitive data using a heuristic and remove it.

E.g.:
Exception logging section

```
catch (Exception e)
{
   logger.Error(e, "Unexpected error while trying to perform request.");
}
```

Exception layout currently used:

```
${exception:format=Message,StackTrace}
```

Comment: Have a look at this issue: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1155 - tl;dr: they suggest using [Replace Layout Renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Replace-Layout-Renderer)

Comment: @Fildor It's not exactly what I had in mind, but it's good enough.